# Oracle assign table permission

Tags: oracle

In Oracle, a table, 'MyTable' is owned by 'User1', how can I grant table access permission to another user, say 'User2' ?

In SQL server, we have some application access permission, does Oracle has something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grant `SELECT` privileges (or `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, and a few others like `REFERENCES`) to a user

```
GRANT SELECT 
   ON user1.MyTable
   TO user2
```

It would be more common, though, to create a role, grant the privileges to the role, and then grant the role to whatever users need it, i.e.

```
CREATE ROLE user1_select;

GRANT SELECT 
   ON user1.MyTable
   TO user1_select;

GRANT user1_select
   TO user2;
```

That makes it easier in the future to grant a single role to more users and to ensure that all the users with a specific job function have the same set of roles rather than trying to make sure that you've granted everyone access to exactly the same set of objects.

Comment: can you give me a query to show user permission for a table ?

Comment: @user595234 - `dba_tab_privs` (or `all_tab_privs` or `user_tab_privs` depending on your privileges and what tables you are interested in) will show you what privileges users have on a table.  `role_tab_privs` will show you what privileges roles have on a table.  Since roles can be granted to roles, roles can be granted to users either as default or non-default, roles can be password protected, etc. it can be a bit challenging to work out what users have what access to a table via roles in what circumstances unless you make some simplifying assumptions.